# How to use "more" properly

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction

I really wonder which sentence below is correct with using "more".

> We have 2 hours **more**.

Or

> We have 2 **more** hours.

What I was thinking about "more" is that the second sentence sounds correct. but I am still not sure..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both of them are correct, but the second sentence is more commonly used.
The first example could be taken as a more formal use of language.

Answer (score 0):

The second sentance sounds natural.

How much longer?

We have 2 more hours.

How long before we go home?

We have 2 more hours.